Azure Integration Runtime Error Azure data Factory
Have a peculiar issue. Have created a created an integration runtime that connect to onprem SQL servers. Have two users one with read access and another with developer access. Both users used to connect fine to the SQL server without any issues. Suddenly the user with select access is not connecting to the SQL server, keep getting error to check the connectivity to the sql server. The user works fine when logging using the SSMS. User with developer access is able to connect to the SQL server without any issue from Azure Data factory But the other user errors out.
Tried to reset the user password.

can you add the error message you are getting?

As per this  Ms Document  below are the possible solutions to resolve the issue:

Make sure outbound traffic over port 1433 will allowed by your network's firewall.

Add the IP address of the self-hosted integration runtime machine to the list of allowed IP addresses.

Confirm that the linked service in ADF is correctly configured for the read-access user.

Recheck the connection string, username, and password used in the linked service.

Ensure you have selected correct database.
It tested successfully after following above steps:




@George Mathew Check if above provided solution works for you?
